# “Unresponsive Script" on close of Windows Form

Tags: c#, xulrunner

I am using c# .Net windows app. In this I have used xulrunner 22.0 + Geckofx 22.0 from bitbucket.

I have used Geckofx browser to display flash content in my app.

Whenever I close a windows form I get an message

> "Unresponsive Script"
>
> 'A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.
>   You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script
>   will complete.'

Any Ideas?

Comment: have you tried things like manually disposing the geckofx browser whenever the form is closed?

Comment: Yes I have tried it but no success!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using GeckoPreference to set `dom.max_script_run_time` to a larger value than default or to 0 to disable it.

```
GeckoPreferences.User["dom.max_script_run_time"] = 0;
```

Ensure you do this after your call to `Xpcom.Initialize`.

Comment: Just one doubt? Why: "GeckoPreferences.User" and why not "GeckoPreferences.Default" because I have already used flash content and I am using "Gecko.GeckoPreferences.Default["extensions.blocklist.enabled"] = false;"